# For which $k$ can a vertex-transitive graph on $n$ vertices have $k\cdot n$ automorphisms?

Tags: graph-theory, automorphism-group

Given a vertex-transitive graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, the number of automorphisms of $G$ will be $k\cdot n$, where $k$ is the number of automorphisms fixing a given vertex. I have examples for the following $k$:

- $k=1$: The path of length 1, the graph of the snub cube, the Cayley graph associated to any graphical regular representation (GRR) as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/953905/).
- $k=2$: All nontrivial cycles, many other graphs (e.g. the [Holt graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holt_graph))
- $k=3$: The cubic symmetric graphs $F_{26}A, F_{38}A, F_{42}A, F_{56}A,  F_{62}A, F_{74}A, F_{78}A, F_{86}A$, probably many more such.
- $k=4$: The [Franklin graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FranklinGraph.html), the $12$-circulant graph $(2,3,6)$.
- $k=2m$ for $m\ge3$: The graph of the uniform tiling with $m$ triangles meeting at a vertex, which for $m=3,4,5$ are Platonic solids, for $m=6$ is the standard tiling of the Euclidean plane by triangles, and for $m\ge7$ is an infinite hyperbolic tiling.

I do not know of any graphs which obtain odd $k$ greater than $3$, but I suspect such graphs exist; examples are welcomed, especially a general construction yielding all odd $k$. (I would also be interested to see a construction for $k=2m$ using finite rather than infinite graphs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take two disjoint copies of any $m$-vertex $k=1$ example, we get an example with $k=m$. (Take the complement, if you'd like a connected graph.) This seems to get examples for many values of $k$ via the GRR construction.

To start off with, Theorem 2 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(71)90019-0) says that every dihedral group except for $D_3, D_4, D_5$ has a GRR. This gives us every even $k \ge 12$, and the examples in the question give the other even $k$. So it's odd $k$ that we need to worry about.

The paper "GRRs for nonsolvable groups" by Chris Godsil, which I can't find online but is presumably accurately summarized [by this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617354), tells us that we can get a GRR for all groups of order $\ge 32$ except for two cases:

- abelian groups of exponent $\ge 2$, and
- generalized dicyclic groups, defined for example [here](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/%7Emorris/Research/Dicyclic131002.pdf), which all have even order anyway.

A nonabelian group of order $k$ exists iff $k$ is divisible by either $p^3$ for some prime $p$, or else by $p^iq$ for some primes $p,q$ where $p^i \equiv 1 \pmod q$. (In the first case, we add on some cyclic factors to the nonabelian group $C_p^2 \rtimes C_p$; in the second, to the nonabelian group $C_p^i \rtimes C_q$, where the modular condition is necessary for a nontrivial semidirect product to exist.)

This gives us a construction for all the odd numbers $>32$ in [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A060652), including for example all odd multiples of $21$ (taking $(C_7 \rtimes C_3) \times C_m$ for any odd $m$). There are gaps in some awkward cases: notably, any prime $k$.

---

For an easier finite $k=4m$ example, take two disjoint copies of $C_m$.

Mathematica found me a few explicit examples of graphs with odd $k$ in its database: the graphs it calls

```
{"DifferenceSetIncidence", {19, 9, 4}}, 
{"DifferenceSetIncidence", {23, 11, 5}}, 
{"DifferenceSetIncidence", {37, 9, 2}}, 
{"DifferenceSetIncidence", {47, 23, 11}}, 
{"Hadamard", {20, 1}}, 
{"Hadamard", {24, 36}}
```

have $k$ values of $9, 11, 9, 23, 171, 253$, respectively. Also, Mathematica's `{"RegularNonplanarDiameter", {6, 3, 111}}` is a $111$-vertex graph with $k=3$, so two disjoint copies of this graph give us a $222$-vertex graph with $k=999$.

Comment: Thanks for all the examples! I can find a few quotes (though not with a source) saying that there is a GRR for every group which "has order at least 32 and is neither abelian with exponent greater than two nor generalized dicyclic" (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/617354/). I haven't been able to find much info about generalized dicyclic groups, though - in particular I don't know how to prove that a group isn't one. But this seems like it could yield several more odd $k$?

Comment: The citation I found for that in [this paper](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~morris/Research/Dicyclic131002.pdf) is "C. D. Godsil, GRRs for nonsolvable groups, Algebraic methods in graph theory, Vol.I, II (Szeged, 1978), pp. 221–239, Colloq. Math. Soc. J ́anos Bolyai, Amsterdam-NewYork, 1981" so maybe Chris Godsil was just being modest when he answered that other question? I'll edit my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, we still can't get all odd $k$, but this simplifies my description of which $k$ we can get, if nothing else.